# What does the Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int indicate

Tags: laravel

I did some math operation trying to deduct one variable from another variable but fails to give me a results say 30 - 10 returns an error. If I change ->first('leave_entitlement'); to ->sum('leave_entitlement'); and able to do the deduction. However I am not summing leave_entitlement. How to I do it right? please

Leave Model function

```
 public static function getSumOfLeaveTaken($leave_category_id){
            
      
            $total_leave_taken = DB::table('leaves')
            ->where('created_by', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('leave_category_id', $leave_category_id)
            ->sum('num_days');


            return $total_leave_taken ;
        }
```

LeaveBalance Model function

```
public static function getNumOfLeaveEntitlment(){
            
      $leaveEntitlement  = DB::table('salary_level_user')
    ->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)->first('leave_entitlement');

    return $leaveEntitlement;
}
```

Inside my Leave Controller

```
$total_leave_taken = Leave::getSumOfLeaveTaken($request->leave_category_id);

$leaveEntitlement = LeaveBalance::getNumOfLeaveEntitlment();

$total_leave_balance = (int)$leaveEntitlement - (int)$total_leave_taken ;
```

Comment: I have a problem in returning the value of $leaveEntitlement the right way. I am looking for the right query in my LeaveBalance Model static function to give me a single value where I can do operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

Replace ->first with ->value to return a single value and there you can do the deductions

```
->first('leave_entitlement')
```

replace with

```
->value('leave_entitlement')
```